# Random generated number

Tags: java, random

How would you set up a program using Java to generate a 5 digit number using the following statement:

```
int n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*100000+1)
```

It also has to print the number generated.  I have tried writing this different ways and keep coming up with errors.

Comment: If this is homework, please use the "Homework" tag.

Comment: Instead of calling `Math.random()` why not use `java.util.Random`?

Comment: I wont downmode you because SO will take me reputation.

Comment: What are the errors that you keep getting?

Comment: Math.random() provides uniform random numbers, make sure those are what you need. Other distributions exist as well.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of looking at your problem.  Either you need to make sure the random number generator only produces numbers with exactly five digits (in the range 10000 - 99999) or you need to print the numbers with leading 0s when a number is produced that's too low.

The first approach is best met using Java's [Random](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(90000) + 10000;
System.out.println(n);
```

If you're restricted in some way that you *must* use the statement in your question, then the second approach is probably what you're after.  You can use Java's [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to format a random number with leading zeros before printing.

```
n = (int)Math.floor( Math.random() * 100000 + 1 );
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00000");
String number = formatter.format(n);
System.out.println("Number with lading zeros: " + number);
```

Answer (score 2):

One might do:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*100000+1);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

However, this really isn't the preferred way of generating random integers. Check out the [Random](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

Comment: You still need to format the output for the 10% of cases where the randomly generated number has fewer than 5 digits.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random();
for (;;) {
  System.out.println(10000 + r.nextInt(90000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better idea is to generate the number by successively generating 5 random digits. Making the first digit non-zero ensures that the generated number is always 5-digit. I'm posting pseudocode below, it should be easy to convert it into Java code.

```
A = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
B = List(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

output = 0

output=random.choice(A) //first digit from A, no zeros

for i=0 to 4
   output=output*10
   output=output+random.choice(B) //next digits from B, can have zero

return output
```

Look up the API docs for Random if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get a random number 00000 - 99999 is to use the following.

```
Random r= new Random();
// possibly too obtuse for most readers. ;)
System.out.println((""+(100000+r.nextInt(100000))).substring(1));
```